# Call to a member function row() on a non-object when updating a table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter to develop my app. And I am using jquery to send some json data.

This is my code :
Model :

```
public function updateRequest($id_request, $jenis_request, $keluhan ){
    $data= array(
            'jenis_request' => $jenis_request,
            'keluhan' => $keluhan
        );

    $this->db->where('id_request', $id_request);
    $query = $this->db->update('tbl_requestfix', $data);

    return $query->row();
```

controller :

```
public function updateRequest(){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $jenis_request = $_POST['jenis_request'];
    $keluhan = $_POST['keluhan'];

    $row = $this->model_request->updateRequest($id, $jenis_request, $keluhan );
    echo json_encode($row);
}
```

This is the view using ajax

```
$('#btn-footer').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var id = $("#mainTitle strong").text().split("/").pop();

   /*get value checkbox*/
   var jenis_request = [];//console.log($("input[name='request[]']"));                                
    $("input[name='request[]']:checked").each(function() {
          //console.log($(this).val());
          jenis_request .push($(this).val());
     });

     jenis_request = jenis_request.join(',');
     alert(jenis_request); //for check

     /*ambil keluhan*/
     var keluhan = $('#modalkeluhan').val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo base_url() . 'control_closing/updateRequest/' ?>',
                    type : 'POST',
                    data : {id : id ,
                            jenis_request : jenis_request,
                            keluhan : keluhan
                           },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (obj) {
                        console.log(obj);
                    }                                

                });
            });
```

I got this error, Call to a member function row() on a non-object , 
I know that row() is an object, is that a problem ?

Comment: `$query->row() ` works on select statement not on `update` query

Comment: So, I must using what ?

Comment: what do you expect `$row` value at controllers `updateRequest` function

Comment: I just wanna see th e json is created or not ?

Comment: because, the html tag is still following like in my textarea that i take using jquery ajax == > var keluhan = $('#modalkeluhan').val();

Answer (score 3):

This may help you

```
public function updateRequest($id_request, $jenis_request, $keluhan )
{
    $data= array(
        'jenis_request' => $jenis_request,
        'keluhan' => $keluhan
    );

    $this->db->where('id_request', $id_request);
    $query = $this->db->update('tbl_requestfix', $data);
    $affected_rows=$this->db->affected_rows();
    if($affected_rows >0)
    {
        return $affected_rows." rows updated";//return here the way you want
    }
    else
    {
        return "No updates";
    }
}
```